# Combines two fields in asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, html, xml, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I need to make a dropdownlist combining two fields from an xml file...

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<exchangeRates>
<rate country="aud" >0.97</rate>
<rate country="usd" >1.01</rate>
</exchangeRates>
```

I need for the dropdownlist to show country and the rate like

```
aud    0.97
usd    1.01
```

Something like

```
SELECT country + rate AS NewColumn FROM XML above

And then use NewColumn for the DataValueFIeld:

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="SqlDBSrc" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="NewColumn"
>

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="ListItems" runat="server" DataFile="~/ExchangeRates.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

How do I do this correctly in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use LINQ to XML.
 Something like (not tested)

```
dim selectList = (from x in xmldoc
                select new SelectListItem { Text = x.Attribute("country") + ' '+ x.Value, Value = x.Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ad a pre-render event to the control and modify the control there

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onprerender="DropDownList1_PreRender"
DataSourceID="SqlDBSrc" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="Value"
>
```

Note: adjust the DataText and DataValue Fields to populate the unmodified data.

In your code behind, this modifies the :

```
protected void DropDownList1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
    {
        item.Text = item.Text + " " + item.Value;
    }
}
```

This is one way to do it but there may be other better ways before binding the list.

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="**CALL_NAMESURNAME**" 
                DataValueField="CALL_NAME">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:McCarthyConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CALL_NAME], [SURNAME],**CALL_NAME + SURNAME AS [CALL_NAMESURNAME]** FROM [Sheet1$] where COY_NAME LIKE '%abc%'">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>`

Check the ** ** parts.